# Start software updates in several SCCM client, from one remote location

Tags: sccm

To be honest, I really do not know how I should to start to do this. I tried to search on it, but I did not find what I am looking for. So what I want is an application, which loops through on several server with SCCM client, and start the software updates on all with one button.

Could you help please, how I should to start it?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean of "start the software updates"? If you want to invoke Installation of Software updates on a remote computer, try this.

[Invoke Installation of Software updates on a remote computer](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Invoke-Installation-of-fc08c3e5)

Best Regards,
Ray